# how preset values of variables in functions that will be called later

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I know that when user click the links, the variable i holds the value of 3. But what if you want to get *link1* when clik first link, *link2* if you click second link and so. Is it possible to get such result?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="p1">linklisthere</p>
<script>
text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
text += '<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=alert("link"+i);>presshere</a></div>';
}
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

maybe this issue has to do with *closures* a concept that I haven't fully understanding.

Comment: Given your inline handler approach, you could create a global variable, or just put a property directly on the element. Then increment that variable or property on each click. `onclick=alert("link"+(this.i=this.i+1||1));` http://jsfiddle.net/A3XyH/ Either way, it's cleaner to put the code in a function and have it invoke that function.

Comment: First sign things have gone wrong: `javascript:void` in a javascript string, second sign you've gone way off track: `onclick=` in a javascript string. Look into [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
text += '<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=alert("link"+i);>presshere</a</div>';
```

The variable i is being interpreted as part of the string NOT as the variable.  In order to fix this you must put '+i+' instead, as shown below

```
text += '<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(\'link'+i+'\');">presshere</a></div>';
```

I also fixed your `<a>` tag that wasn't closed properly and put quotes around your click function.

Personally I would rewrite your code to look like this

```
text += '<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(this.title)" title="link'+i+'">presshere</a></div>';
```

That would remove the need for back slashing quotes and makes it easier to read

Comment: your first suggestion causes this error "unexpected token }", why?

Comment: Oops, I appologise, small error with quotation marks.  I used the wrong ones in the answer but the right ones in the jsfiddle.
Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
text += '<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=alert("link"+i);>presshere</a</div>';
```

The `i` is in the text, you need to bring it out of the string, close the anchor tag, and put the javascript into quotes.

```
text += '<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(\"link\"+'+i+');">presshere</a></div>';
```

Comment: I think you mean `'alert("link' + i + '")'`. Assuming you want the HTML to read `alert("link1")`.

Comment: there is a lot more missing than just that, no quotes around the alert, didnt close the </a>

Comment: you are right, I just edited and corrected that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't about closures, it's that you're using a global variable to report the value of *i*. You can use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to avoid that:

```
<p id="p1">linklisthere</p>
<script>
// Use an IIFE to avoid globals for code that runs once and
// doesn't need to persist
(function() {
  var i = 0,
      link,
      p = document.getElementById('p1');

  while (i < 3) {

    // Use DOM methods to construct elements, using innerHTML is
    // ok but gets clunky for anything complex
    link = document.createElement('span');
    link.style.cursor = 'pointer';  // Should be implemented using a class or CSS

    // Use an IIFE to break the closure to i
    link.onclick = (function(num) {
      return function() {
        alert('link' + num);
      }
    }(i));

    // Counter could be incremented in the above call but here is clearer
    i++;

    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('press here'));
    p.appendChild(link);

    // help layout a bit for this example
    p.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  }
}());
</script>
```

Note that you shouldn't use an A element if you don't actually want one. Use style to give users a hint that they can click on the item, and follow [WAI](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) recommendations to assist with accessibility (e.g. add [`role="link"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_link_role) to the span).